# How to create 3d scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly, scatter3d

Proficients in Plotly, help me please. I have a matrix with heights. I need to build an analogue of go.Surface using Scatter. If this is not possible, then mark the points (vertices) on the Surface chart. All this is needed to better determine the vertices. Thank you.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=z_data.values))
#fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(z=z_data.values))
fig.update_layout(title='Mt Bruno Elevation', autosize=False,
              width=500, height=500,
              margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))

fig.show()
```

Similar to this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience with 3D graphs. I created a scatterplot 3D from your data, I assigned columns of data frames to the y-axis, assigned rows of data frames to the x-axis, converted the z-axis to a 1D list of data frame elements and drew it. Does this meet the intent of the question?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv',index_col=0)

x_tmp = z_data.index.tolist()
xx = [[t]*24 for t in x_tmp]
xx = sum(xx, [])

y_tmp = z_data.columns.tolist()
yy = [int(t) for t in y_tmp]
yy = yy * 25

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=xx, y=yy,
                           z=sum(z_data.values.tolist(),[]),
                           mode='markers',
                          marker=dict(size=2)))
#fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(z=z_data.values))

fig.update_layout(title='Mt Bruno Elevation', autosize=True,
              width=800, height=800,
              margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))

fig.show()
```

[image]